# Limit the number of attachments before onActivityResult() is called

Tags: android, attachment, onactivityresult, android-external-storage

I have a File Uploading module in my App where on button click, files from external storage directory ( Google Drive) are selected and are uploaded. Based on the requirement, I can select 5 files maximum, which can be done by selecting 5 files at once or in split like 2 files first then again 3 files. I just want to notify the user once more than 5 files are selected. Presently I am able to  notify the user once onActivityResult() is called. Is there any way I can restrict the selection to only 5 files and notify the user from the Google Drive itself?

Please find my presently working code below:

```
   txtv_attach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int_permission_type = 1;
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if (CheckingPermissionIsEnabledOrNot()) {

                    Toast.makeText(myContext, "All Permissions Granted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    start_attachment_activity();
                }

                // If, If permission is not enabled then else condition will execute.
                else {

                    //Calling method to enable permission.
                    RequestMultiplePermission();

                }
            }

            else
            {
                start_attachment_activity();
            }
        }
    });
```

Now the start_attachment_activity():

```
  public void  start_attachment_activity()
{
    String[] mimeTypes =
            {"image/*","application/pdf","application/msword","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint","application/vnd.ms-excel","text/plain","audio/", "video/"};

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());
    Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    chooseFile.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");
    chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    chooseFile.setType("*/*");
    chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
    startActivityForResult(chooseFile, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
}
```

Now the onActivityResult():

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

                if (data.getData() != null) {
                    if((alst_attachmentNames.size()+1)>5)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(myContext,"attachment of 5 or less than 5 items are allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Uri dataURI = data.getData();
                        try {
                            String path= getFilePath(getActivity(), dataURI);
                            if(path!=null)
                            {
                                alst_attachmentPaths.add(path);
                                alst_attachmentNames.add(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
                                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=
                                        new LinearLayoutManager(myContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                                RecyclerView.Adapter attachmentAdapter = new attachmentAdapter(myContext, alst_attachmentNames);
                                rvw_attachmentList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                                rvw_attachmentList.setAdapter(attachmentAdapter);
                            }


                        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                            String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"SD Card failed":e.getMessage();
                            Log.e("sdcard-err2:",err);
                        }

                    }


                }
                if (data != null) {
                    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                    if (clipData != null) {

                        if(clipData.getItemCount()>5 || (clipData.getItemCount()+alst_attachmentNames.size())>5  )
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(myContext,"attachment of 5 or less than 5 items are allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                                Uri uri = item.getUri();

                                //In case you need image's absolute path
                                try {
                                    String path= getFilePath(getActivity(), uri);
                                    alst_attachmentPaths.add(path);
                                    alst_attachmentNames.add(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
                                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=
                                    new LinearLayoutManager(myContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                            RecyclerView.Adapter attachmentAdapter = new attachmentAdapter(myContext, alst_attachmentNames);
                            rvw_attachmentList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                            rvw_attachmentList.setAdapter(attachmentAdapter);

                    }
                    }
                }

            }
            break;

    }
}
```

If there is something I am missing, please do let me know. I want to control the number of file selection from the drive itself. Need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `alst_attachmentNames`. ??? Who is filling that array list? I see no connection wirh ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: `start_attachment_activity()` ??? You are not starting an activity. Nor do i see attachments. The user is going to select some content.

Comment: @greenapps: Please do understand that start_attachment_activity() is just a method name and has no other relevance to it. The arrayList is filled inside the onActivityResult().

Comment: Then show that arraylist code. Any reaon to omit it?

Comment: And please use method names that represent the task.

Comment: @greenapps: Please check the else condition inside onActivityResult(), the arrayList is being filled there.

Comment: Impossible code. You are inspecting the size() before filling?

Comment: @greenapps: I dont understand what's so impossible. An arrayList without being filled returns 0 as size.

Comment: But you are checking size() for > 5 isnt it? Why if it == 0?

Comment: @greenapps: yes exactly. For the first time if I am selecting 2 items, while checking it will return 0. But next time while again checking, the size will return 2. The basic intention behind this is to check the total  number of items selected before uploading. If the size is 0, it will go to else condition and it won't show the toast. Can you please tell me what really confusing you? I mean the exact issue?

Comment: I do not understand what limiting the size of an arraylist has to do with the possibility that the user with ACTION_GET_CONTENT selects, or can select, more than five files.

Comment: @greenapps: That ArrayList is just for displaying the user which are the files that are been selected. The arraylist fills up a recyclerview which shows the list of item selected. While one arraylist contains the name, the other arraylist contains the path to the file. Later on from the path, I am accessing the file for uploading.

Comment: You cannot tell ACTION_GET_CONTENT to let the user only select five files. So you do not have to show any onActivityResult code.

Comment: Please check once, when the arraylist has length more than 5, thst means already 5 files have been selected, in that case that case of more than 5 files will come. V=Can you please suggest the more appropriate option instead of ACTION_GET_CONTENT ?

Comment: Sorry i do not understand your remark. And i think you did not understand mines.

Comment: You cannot limit the number of files that the user can select using MULTIPLE. Remove the multiple so the user can only select one file every time. Then you are in control.

Comment: @greenapps: Thank you. Is there no way that I can choose multiple as well as limit the number of files selected?